# All files are being changed in pull request, but there are just a few file changes

Tags: git

I tried to pushed some new code after I changed my terminal from powershell to zsh. I just changed 3 files but suddenly ALL files are "changed", but they are still the same..

According to the diff log in github they are being deleted and added again.

I would assume it is a whitespace configuration problem, maybe something with UTF and that kind of stuf, but I don't now how to fix it, I want my commit to only the files I changed not every file

[image: Github "diff" log]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your new zsh terminal, try and clone your repository again, after setting a global configuration regarding eol ([end of lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline), to avoid automatic transformation of all files):

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
git clone -b yourPRBranch https://github.com/you/yourRepo
cd yourRepo
# report your work on those 3 files
git add .
git commit -m "Add 3 files modified"
git push
```

Comment: Thanks, you answer is useful. But I said 3 files to over-simplify, there are really like 30 files, is there a way to do it without cloning it and passing manually all files?

Comment: @SvenBrodersen you can clone and add all modified files with: `git --work-tree=../path/to:first/clone add .`: that should import all your modifications.